# Salesforce Internal Error in Lightning with Gack Id 1747963889

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-experience, gack

Why   Salesforce Internal Error in Lightning is generated with Gack Id 1747963889?

How to reproduce it?

Comment: Gack ID can be different. But steps to reproduce will same.

Comment: Due to this article https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html each gack id should be a different case with different common stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement @auraEnabled method with Integer parameter.

Pass Integer to @auraEnabled; perform i++ inside of that method.