# Gack Id "-1079455898" in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, gack

Any reasons or steps to reproduce for Lightning Salesforce Internal error with gack id "-1079455898"?

Please note: this is not duplicate of [Salesforce Internal Error in Lightning with Gack Id 1747963889](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149734/salesforce-internal-error-in-lightning-with-gack-id-1747963889) since gack id is different and reason is different.

Comment: Isn't a duplicate question and similar answer? I believe you can write many different questions as each time you will get different Gack Id.

Comment: No, the gack id is different and steps to reproduce are different.

Comment: There is no different except better explanation. The only different is here `i+1` instead of `i++` which is not a difference. I am leaving this to you. (no further comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement lightning app with apex controller with @auraEnabled method with Integer parameter.

Pass Integer to @auraEnabled method and perform Integer x = i + 1 inside of that method.

Comment: I just ran into this GACK Id and in my case the Integer was being use as the comparison in a for loop `for(Integer x=0,x<THENUMBER;x++)` has to pass a string then convert to a integer in method

Comment: you need to pass a string and then convert to integer inside of apex controller class. Integer numberInteger = Integer.valueOf( numberPassedAsAStringParameter )